PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null) xcode
I am working on the iOS version of my flutter app. I am getting multiple errors like PlatformException channel-error when I am using path provider of flutter. For shared preferences package of flutter I am getting the error
Unable to establish connection on channel: "dev.flutter.pigeon.shared_preferences_foundation.LegacyUserDefaultsApi.getAll"., null, null

When I try to use a database using floor I get the message
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)

It seems like the iOS and flutter are not able to communicate properly. I will share my appdelegate file, pod file and the pubspec file here.
The appdelegate
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("my_api_key")

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

The pod file
platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), _FILE_)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(_FILE_))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

The pubspec file
name: inhrm
description: InHRM Flutter Application

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.13.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.1.5
  cached_network_image: 3.3.1
  camera: ^0.10.0+1
  flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.0
  background_fetch: ^1.3.7
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  connectivity_plus: ^2.0.3
  dartz: ^0.10.0
  device_info: ^2.0.3
  dio: ^4.0.4
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  file_picker: ^5.0.1
  firebase_analytics: ^10.1.1
  fl_chart: ^0.55.1
  floor: ^1.2.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
  flutter_calendar_carousel: ^2.1.0
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_map: ^2.2.0
  flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1
  flutter_typeahead: ^3.1.3
  flutter_phone_direct_caller: ^2.1.1
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  geocoding: ^2.0.1
  geolocator: ^11.0.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
  http: ^0.13.4
  image_cropper: ^4.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  json_annotation: ^4.3.0
  location: ^4.3.0
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.7
  photo_manager: ^3.0.0-dev.2
  provider: ^6.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.9
  table_calendar: ^3.0.3
  url_launcher: ^6.0.16
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.12
  firebase_core: ^2.15.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.5
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.0.0
  get: ^4.6.5
  pop: ^0.1.1
  helpers: ^1.2.3
  store_redirect: ^2.0.1
  webview_flutter: ^4.4.4
  permission_handler: ^11.2.0
  background_location_tracker: ^1.4.0
  workmanager: ^0.5.2
  file_saver: ^0.2.4
  flutter_background_service:
  flutter_background_service_android: ^2.0.4

dependency_overrides:

dev_dependencies:
  floor_generator: ^1.2.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - lib/app/localization/lang/

  fonts:
    - family: OpenSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 700
    - family: OpenSansCondensed
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans_Condensed/OpenSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans_Condensed/OpenSansCondensed-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/font/Open_Sans_Condensed/OpenSansCondensed-LightItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 300

No package is able to communicate with the channels properly. I seem to find no solutions. can anyone help me in this regard. Thanks in advance
I have already tried using commands like flutter clean and flutter pub get, reinstall pod, also tried upgrading the flutter sdk version and upgrading package versions.
